# bash scripting to add users

Tags: bash, cut

I created a bash script to read information such as username, group etc., from a text file and create users based on it in linux. The code seems to function properly and creates the users as desired. But the user information in the last line of the text file always gets misinterpreted. Even if i delete it then the next last line gets misinterpreted i.e., the text is read wrongly.
`

```
#!/bin/bash
userfile="users.txt"
IFS=$'\n'
if [ ! -f "$userfile" ]
then
  echo "File does not exist. Specify a valid file and try again. "
  exit
fi
groups=(`cut -f 4 "$userfile" | sed 's/ //'`)
fullnames=(`cut -f 1 "$userfile" | sed 's/,//' | sed 's/"//g'`)
username1=(`cut -f 1 "$userfile" |sed 's/,//' | sed 's/"//' | tr [A-Z] [a-z] | awk '{print substr($2,1,1) substr($3,1,1) substr($1,1,1)}'`)
username2=(`cut -f 4 "$userfile" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] | awk '{print substr($1,1,1)}'`)
i=0
n=${#username1[@]}
for (( q=0; q<n; q++ ))
do
usernames[$q]=${username1[$q]}"${username2[$q]}"
done
declare -a usernames
x=0
created=0
for user in ${usernames[*]}
do
adduser -c ${fullnames[$x]} -p 123456789 -f 15 -m -d /home/${groups[$x]}/$user -K LOGIN_RETRIES=3 -K PASS_MAX_DAYS=30 -K PASS_WARN_AGE=3 -N -s /bin/bash $user 2> /dev/null
usermod -g ${groups[$x]} $user
chage -d 0 $user
  let created=$created+1
x=$x+1
echo -e "User $user created    " 
done
echo "$created Users created"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y50ZI.png)`

Comment: Check your script with [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net)

Comment: Use `bash -x yourscript` to log each line run, then go through that log to identify a specific, narrow, bug, asking a question *only* about that bug (ie. building a [mcve] that just reproduces the bug, rather than posting your whole original script).

Comment: (Also, in general, `array=( $string )` is bad practice -- if your string contains `*` as a word, for example, you'll get a list of files in your array. If you *must* split a string to form an array, use `read -a`, or -- if splitting on newlines and using bash 4.0 or newer -- `readarray` or `mapfile`).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

userfile="./users.txt"; #  <-- Config

while read line; do

    # FULL NAME
        # Capture all between quotes as full name
        fullname=$(printf '%s' "${line}" | sed 's/^"\(.*\)".*/\1/')

        # Remove spaces and punctuations???:
        fullname=$(printf '%s' "${fullname}" | tr -d '[:punct:][:blank:]')

    # Right-side names:
        partb=$(printf '%s' "${line}" | sed "s/^\".*\"//g")

        # CODE 1, capture second row
        code1=$(printf '%s' "${partb}" | cut -f 2 )

        # CODE 2, capture third row
        code2=$(printf '%s' "${partb}" | cut -f 3 )

        # GROUP, capture fourth row
        group=$(printf '%s' "${partb}" | cut -f 4 )

    # Print only for report
    echo "fullname: ${fullname}\n code 1: ${code1}\n code 2: ${code2}\n group: ${group}\n"

done <${userfile}
```

Maybe these are the fields that you want, now you have it in variables for manipulate them: $fullname, $code1, $code2 and $group.

Although maybe the fail that you observed was due to some misplaced quotation mark in the text file or the line breaks, on the attached screenshot I can see one missed quote.

Comment: If you want to break a line into three variables, one for each of the first three columns, why all that mess with `cut` instead of just `read -r code1 code2 group <<<"$line"`?

Comment: Similarly, builtin parameter expansion can much more efficiently do the work of removing punctuation and spaces: `fullname=${fullname//[[:punct:][:blank:]]/}`

Comment: ...you could similarly remove spaces between the first and last quote in a string with `fullname=${fullname//'"'*'"'/}`. See [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) for a general introduction to native string manipulation in bash.

Comment: I used cut under read because first you have to separate the 'full names' that are of variable spaces, although surely there are ways to do it in less lines.

Comment: That explains why it's `read line` at the top. It *doesn't* explain why you use three `cut`s later, instead of a single additional `read`. So I should have said `<<<"$partb"` rather than `<<<"$line"`, to be keeping your variable naming conventions.

Comment: That said, my concern isn't really with minimizing number of lines, but with minimizing the number of processes being started on a per-line basis. Doing a whole lot of `mkfifo()`s, `fork()`s, `wait()`s, etc. for every line of input processed is the exact kind of behavior that gets shell languages their excessively-sluggish reputation. (By contrast, if you had just *one* copy of `sed` and *one* `tr` that processed the entire input stream, outside the loop -- and then looped over their output using only builtins -- that would be far more efficient).

Comment: I understand, could you post the performance improvements on the script? sounds really good :-)

Comment: `read -r _ code1 code2 group _ <<<"$partb"` gets you there with respect to splitting out `code1`, `code2` and `group` from the second, third and fourth columns of `partb`. Without input provided to test against, I'm hesitant to provide a full rewrite (and frankly, I'm on the close vote on this one -- the question should really be rewritten with a [mcve] focused on a specific problem -- so I'm hesitant to answer the question myself). Or are you asking me to post benchmarks?

Comment: By way of benchmarks -- on my local system, `time bash -c 'partb="qux foo bar baz"; for ((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do code1=$(printf '%s' "${partb}" | cut -f 2 ); done'` takes 3.9s, whereas `time bash -c 'partb="qux foo bar baz"; for ((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do read _ code1 code2 group _ <<<"$partb"; done'` takes 0.67s. So with the `read` approach we can read *all three* variables from 1000 lines of input in 2/3rds of a second, whereas with the `cut` approach we can read only one variable from 1000 lines in 4 seconds.

Comment: ...which is to say that once we normalize for number of variables populated, we're 17x faster with the parameter expansion. And the slowest thing in *that* is going to be the heredoc (`<<<"$partb"`), since it involves creating a temporary file; performance could be improved further if we did without it (in a way that didn't create other overhead -- a process substitution or a pipeline will both cost more).